# WCF Help Page: add comments?

Tags: wcf, webhttp

I have made Help Page as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx

Now the output looks like this:

```
Url: http://localhost/IDataRESTService/getnode/{NODE_ID}?t={TYPE}
HTTP Method: GET
Message direction   Format  Body
Request     N/A     The Request body is empty.
Response    Unknown     The Response body cannot be inferred
```

1. Is it possible to add comments to the standard WCF Help Page?
   For example: I'd like to add parameters description, how to use the method etc.
2. Is it possible to add to the output formatted comments /// from the source code?